# Finding maximum value of periodic function.

Tags: periodic-functions

In my question, It is asked to find the maximum value of the equation of motion such as u_t=(11/210)*sin(10*t)-(1/21)*sin(t*11). I have found that when t=2pi*n/21 it reached its maximum value. But it is obvious from its graph and calculations that the value of function increases from n=1 to n=10 and equals to 0.0997 when n=11. After that, it decreases. My question is there any way to calculate it more easily or it is what it is?

Comment: What do you mean by "more easily"?

Comment: Use $$d/dt(f(t))=0$$ and you'll get cosine functions on LHS and then use $$Cos[10(t/10+2nπ/10)=Cos 10[{ (11/10)t+(2mπ/10)t } ]$$ and then all the values of t for which m and n are integers is extreme points of function and then checking around neighborhood of these points you can get the max and min

Comment: I mean in the exam this question can be asked, and I don't think they want us to calculate by doing all the calculations n=1,2,3... I want to know is there any way to calculate max. value another way?

Answer (score 1):

The graph of a function has slope 0 at it's **maximum point**.

Slope of a function can be determined by dy/dx that is its *derivative*.

So, by equating it's derivative to 0 we get,

dy/dx = {(11/210) * 10 * cos(10t)} - {(1/21) * 11 * cos(11t)} = 0

= (11/21) * [cos(10t) - cos(11t)] = 0     (since, cos(c)-cos(d) we know)

0 = 2 * sin(21t/2) * sin(t/2)

so, we get two cases

sin(21t/2) = 0 or sin(t/2) = 0

Since we know, sin^-1(0) = n*pi

therefore t = 2 * n * pi /21  or t = 2 * n * pi.

and the maximum value by putting the above t value of the function will be 0.099717665

[Check this graph solution for the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQBL6.png)